# How to plot something if a Boolean value is TRUE? Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's my simplified code:

```
PlotOrNot = input.bool(true, title="Plot it", inline = "01")
plot(SomethingCalculated, "Calculated Thing", color=color.blue, offset = offset)
```

As I found [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Inputs.html#boolean-input), there's a way to tell the `plot` command to do the plot in case the Boolean value is true but I could not manage to make it not turn into error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it in the `series` argument of the `plot()`.

```
plot(PlotOrNot ? SomethingCalculated : na, "Calculated Thing", color=color.blue, offset = offset)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect. I added another question (extending the situation) here below, would you please look at it? Thank you. :)